# bootstrap 3 navbar not collapsing on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

i put a collapsing navbar on my website.
the problem is that on mobile the navbar isnt collapsing
what is the problem?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#main"><?php bloginfo ('name') ?></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#contact">צור קשר</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">פרויקטים</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">שירותים</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">אודות</a></li>
          <li><a href="#main">ראשי</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This html markup looks correct did you load jquery before the bootstrap js and what version of jquery are you using if you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code a `<ul><li>` added mistake.
Delete it.
Then your code is working properly.